# Dolphin displaying to little free disk space on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, ssd, dolphin

my SSD has about 100 GB free but Dolphin and df only show about 30. when I go into the trash folder it shows 75 GB. I had a full Drive after leaving siril running (it does stacking for astrophotography and needs alot of diskspace). when I deleted two Folders in Dolphin they didn't move to trash and the free space remained at 0 B but they should have been less than the missing 70 GB. I would guess they were about 10 to 20 GB.
when i went to see the properties of my disk it said used space: 132,1 TiB (145.290.737.414.939). so that is just ridiculus for a 1TB ssd.
[displayed free space in Dolphin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM6GK.png)
[what the df command shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzXXq.png)
[used space in the properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yAvM.png)

I am pretty new to linux and only now the most basic commands (I only found out about df today).

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 on an Acer Aspire V 15 with a Samsung 970EVO (I think. or something similar by samsung evo at least).

Comment: Try the application `filelight` it will give you concentric pie chart representations of the used space on your drives.

Comment: I tried filelight as suggested but it showed different numbers than all the others. I also tried deleting more files but now the trash still shows 75GB and any other folder 205GB. df also changed but I am still missing about 50 GB. the insane 130TiB stayed the same

Comment: Filelight should be helpful because it should show you the path where your problem(s) exists.  Ex: Maybe the software that you left running for hours is the culprit, especially since you know that it writes to disk constantly?  Perhaps the software is not functioning correctly.  File size is not calculated in the same way in every application, so it's never going to be identical between all applications.  It has to do with how files are saved to disk.  For example, if your software is writing a LOT of 1 byte files, they actually will take up 4086 bytes per file assuming 4086 block size.

Comment: siril only writes .fit files. a type of image file. they aren't that small (30-60MB). what I especially don't understand is how even within one application there can be contradictions. like with the df command. i have searched with both filelight and qdirstat and couldn'd find anything weird. also couldn't find the folders I deleted, that dissapeared but didn't free up any space

Comment: *"how even within one application there can be contradictions"*: Because no application that **estimates** file size actually counts every single byte on all your disks every single time the estimate is shown.  In addition to the block size discrepancy I mentioned above there are also differences between the sizes of KB/KiB, and whether or not file sizes are calculated using powers of 10 or 2^x.  Have you gone thru file manager settings and enabled the display/calculation of hidden files?  Enabled all folders in filelight?

Comment: I have had hidden files on in Dolphin but couldn't find anythin I didn't know (at least nothin big enough). but I can't find the option in filelight. could you tell me where to look? thank you for helping by the way

Comment: Settings > Configure Filelight... > Scanning > "Do not scan these folders"

Comment: Ok I have now found the "deleted but not really" folders in "/home/redactedusername/.local/share/Trash/files/" but there is also some stuff one dir up: a file called "directorysizes" and a folder "info" with two files called  "foldername.trashinfo". do you know if i can just delete everything or should i do sonething else?

Comment: I have now found out by deleting some test files, that the reason the folders were missing was because the .trashinfo files were empty. I can now see them in the trash. Now since there were empty files created with 0B left I was wondering if there could have been a rollover since 2⁴⁷=140,737,488,355,328 whitch is remarcably close to the displayed used space right when it started counting. 47 seems weird but I am no expert.

Comment: anything in `/.local/share/Trash` including subfolders are either things you deliberately "deleted" or some software put it there (generally because it's trash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been informed by someone on the [Ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2449531), that the missing space should be reserved by root.

So the remaining problems are really just the wrong free space shown in the Trash folder and the supposed 130Tib of used space, which I can both live with.

And thus I consider this issue resolved (enough)